# How can I inject dependencies into a javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandler using Spring?

Tags: spring, jsf, dependency-injection, exceptionhandler

I have a JSF application using PrimeFaces 6.2 and Spring 5.1.4. I read, that an exception handler can be defined in the `faces-config.xml` like this:

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>my.package.MyExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

I wondered how I could get the dependencies injected into an `ExceptionHandlerFactory` and `ExceptionHandler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this out of the box.
It would be possible by creating an "spring aware" ExceptionHandlerFactory and create the ExceptionHandler instance via Spring but i would just get the beans manually in your ExceptionHandler like: [Best way to manually pull a spring bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262969/best-way-to-manually-pull-a-spring-bean)

Comment: Yep thanks. I have already crated a solution, where in the handle method in my handler I simply let the spring context inject the dependencies on first use. The injection itself is as simple as FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this)